# How can I return a filtering iterator that captures an argument?

Tags: rust, iterator, closures

I'm trying to create an iterator that filters a slice based on an argument.

```rust
fn dates_from_iterator_ref<'a>(
    from: &'a NaiveDate,
    dates: &'a [NaiveDate],
) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a NaiveDate> {
    dates.iter().filter(|&date| date >= from)
}

fn dates_from_iterator_val<'a>(
    from: NaiveDate,
    dates: &'a [NaiveDate],
) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a NaiveDate> {
    dates.iter().filter(|&&date| date >= from)
}
```

Whether I pass the argument as a reference or a value, I get the same error:

```
   |
89 | fn dates_from_iterator_ref<'a>(
   |                            -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
92 | ) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a NaiveDate> {
   |      ----------------------------------- opaque type requires that `from` is borrowed for `'a`
93 |     dates.iter().filter(|&date| date >= from)
   |                         -------         ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                         |
   |                         value captured here
94 | }
   | - `from` dropped here while still borrowed
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the value version, you just need to ensure that the closure captures the value of `date` by moving the value into the capture, rather than borrowing it, by adding the `move` keyword.

Also, as pointed out by @LukasKalbertodt, you [should change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188434/does-a-x-pattern-match-cause-x-to-be-copied) the closure from `|&&date| date >= from` to `|&date| date >= &from`.

```
pub fn dates_from_iterator_val<'a>(
    from: NaiveDate,
    dates: &'a [NaiveDate],
) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a NaiveDate> {
    dates.iter().filter(move |&date| date >= &from)
}
```

For the ref version, the same applies, but it is the reference that gets moved rather than the value:

```
pub fn dates_from_iterator_ref<'a>(
    from: &'a NaiveDate,
    dates: &'a [NaiveDate],
) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a NaiveDate> {
    dates.iter().filter(move |&date| date >= from)
}
```