# Does a '&&x' pattern match cause x to be copied?

Tags: rust, reference, pattern-matching

In the documentation for [std::iter::Iterator::filter()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) it explains that values are passed to the closure by reference, and since many iterators produce references, in that case the values passed are references to references. It offers some advice to improve ergonomics, by using a `&x` pattern to remove one level of indirection, or a `&&x` pattern to remove two levels of indirection.

However, I've found that this second pattern does not compile if the item being iterated does not implement `Copy`:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct Foo(i32);

fn main() {
    let a = [Foo(0), Foo(1), Foo(2)];

    // This works
    let _ = a.iter().filter(|&x| *x != Foo(1));

    // This also works
    let _ = a.iter().filter(|&x| x != &Foo(1));

    // This does not compile
    let _ = a.iter().filter(|&&x| x != Foo(1));
}
```

The error you get is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:14:30
   |
14 |     let _ = a.iter().filter(|&&x| x != Foo(1));
   |                              ^^-
   |                              | |
   |                              | data moved here
   |                              | move occurs because `x` has type `Foo`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                              help: consider removing the `&`: `&x`
```

Does this mean that if I use the `&&x` destructuring pattern, and the value is `Copy`, Rust will silently copy every value I am iterating over? If so, why does that happen?

Answer (score 5):

In Rust, function or closure arguments are irrefutable patterns.

In the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#identifier-patterns), it says:

> By default, identifier patterns bind a variable to a copy of or move
>   from the matched value depending on whether the matched value
>   implements Copy.

So, in this case:

```
let _ = a.iter().filter(|&x| *x != Foo(1));
```

the closure is being passed a reference to a reference to the item being iterated; therefore `x` is bound to a copy of a reference to the item. You can always copy a reference (it is basically a no-op) so this always succeeds.

In this case:

```
let _ = a.iter().filter(|&&x| x != Foo(1));
```

`x` is being bound to a copy of the item itself - which fails if the item is not `Copy`.

The reference also says:

> This can be changed to bind to a reference by using the ref keyword,
>   or to a mutable reference using ref mut.

That's not so useful in this case though: `&&ref x` results in x being a reference to the item, the same as if you had used `&x`.

Comment: I can't think of any case where `ref` would be useful in a function parameter list. Accepting `ref x` basically means that the function takes ownership of some value, but inside the function body you only get access to a reference.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that if I use the `&&x` destructuring pattern, and the value is `Copy`, Rust will silently copy every value I am iterating over?

Yes, that's correct, although the compiler backend might optimize the copying away.

> If so, why does that happen?

Writing `&` before a pattern *dereferences* it. This copies the value it refers to, because a reference only *borrows* its value, so it can't move the value.

Example:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Foo(i32);

let foo: Foo = Foo(5);   // value is owned by foo
let borrow: &Foo = &foo; // value is borrowed
let bar: Foo = *borrow;  // value is copied, the copy is owned by bar
                         // the original value is still owned by foo
```

---

Your first example is a bit special:

```rust
let _ = a.iter().filter(|&x| *x != Foo(1));
```

This seems at first as if it should require the `Copy` trait because `x` is dereferenced twice, first in the pattern, and then in the comparison.

However, the comparison is done by the [PartialEq](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) trait, which takes its arguments by reference. So the above is desugared to:

```rust
let _ = a.iter().filter(|&x| PartialEq::eq(&*x, &Foo(1)));
```

Which works because `&*` cancel each other out. Hence, `x` is only dereferenced once (in the pattern).